# std::set foreign key using custom comaprator

Tags: c++, stl

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,1,1,1,2,2};
auto cmp = [&v](size_t a, size_t b){return v[a] < v[b];};
std::multiset<int, decltype(cmp)> s(cmp);
```

Vector v's contents is just an example. It could be any array of ints, but can have repeating values.

I'm using a multiset because I want to be able to traverse over all the values by-order, and because values in v are not unique.

Also, I'd like to be able to know if a certain value is in it or not.
For example after inserting:

```
s.insert(1);
s.insert(1);
s.insert(2);
s.insert(2);
```

I'd expect for the value of `present` in this test to be `false`:

```
auto iter = s.find(3);
bool present = iter != s.end();
```

However, it is true, I guess it's due to the internal implementation of set (AVL/RB-tree?) and how it searches for values inside using the comparator.
Although, I'd think it should compare the last value to make sure it is what it thinks it is.

Is there an elegant way (without additional helper data structures) to make it "understand" it doesn't hold the value?

Comment: The comparator function is must likely the problem. Try `auto cmp = [](int a, int b){ return a < b; };` - You don't get the _indices_ as arguments to the comparator function. You get two of the values in the `multimap`.

Answer (score 2):

`auto cmp = [&v](size_t a, size_t b){return v[a] < v[b];};`

You're comparing the value of `v[a]` and `v[b]`, not `a` and `b`, in the `cmp` function.

So, if you have `a = 2` and `b = 1`, the `cmp` function will compare `v[2]` and `v[1]`, which is `1` and `1`, then it will return `false`, which is not what you want.

For example, if you want to write a function that compares `v[a]` and `v[b]` using a function, what will you write?

```cpp
bool compare(int a, int b)
{
    return v[a] < v[b];
}
```

or

```cpp
bool compare(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b;
}
```

So, you should change it to this:

`auto cmp = [](int a, int b){return a < b;};`

edit: Here is a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P155Yq3P4) from Ted Lyngmo

Comment: Comparing values in v is intentional since I want a to be ordered by v.

Comment: @user1912594 I have edited my answer to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

According to your `cmp` comparator,`1`, `2` and `3` are all equivalent keys (since `v[1]`, `v[2]` and `v[3]` are all `1`), so `s.find(3) != s.end()` is correct and not implementation specific.

It sounds like you want ordering to happen according to `cmp`, but membership tests according to the default `std::less<int>`. In that case, `std::multiset` alone cannot accommodate you as it uses one comparator for both.